# Doubt in RL circuit and Kirchoffs law

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

We know that kirchoff's second law is based on the fact that in any closed circuit: $$\oint \vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}=0$$

Now let us take a simple LR cirucit with one battery $E$,resistor $R$, inductor $L$. Now let us solve this equation from two ways, Faraday's law, and kirchoff's Law.

Method 1: Faradays Law.

We have $$\oint\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
Accounting for the directions ($\vec{dl}$ is opposite to $\vec {E}$, and parallel to $\delta V$ across resistor) and also $\phi=Li$
$$-E+iR=-L\frac{di}{dt}$$
Method 2 Loop Law:
Let us take the loop so we get:
(Imagined that inductor will make some imaginary battery of opposite polarity and emf $Ldi/dt$)
$$-E+L\frac{di}{dt}+iR=0$$
So both equations are mathematically same. However I got a peculiar doubt that inductor will create some electric field of its own (which is non conservative), which means that ig $\oint\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}\ne0$, so kirchoff's law cant be technically applied here? But ignoring it everything seems to be going fine? So what happens to that extra electric field and is $\delta V\ne0$? please help here.

Comment: This is a [duplicate very many times over](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=kirchhoff%27s+law+inductors).

Comment: Thanks for informing

Comment: It is necessary to use Faraday's law for this precisely inductance behaviour is strictly non-conservative, as you correctly noted. People just love Kirchoff enough to keep patching it with bad fixes like that.